# data migration in wordpress result in domain error

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to make a data migration from remote ip (x.y.z.w) into 127.0.0.1 ,here is my steps in wp version 4.1.

```
1.download database from remote mysql and copy into local pc.
2.install wordpress on 127.0.0.1
3.import database into local mysql
4.
  update  wp_options set option_value="127.0.0.1" where option_name="siteurl";
  update  wp_options set option_value="127.0.0.1" where option_name="home";
```

When i input  127.0.0.1 in firefox ,it is ok.
When i click on the site Admin ,it skip into http://127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1/wp-admin/ , how to fix the bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the protocol, otherwise it's interpreted as a local/relative url:

```
update  wp_options set option_value="http://127.0.0.1" where option_name="siteurl";
                                     ^^^^^^^
```